error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘extern’ - happens when working with header files
I'm currently working on a project that includes multiple source files and header files. I have a weird problem that occurs when I declare a function in a header file.
In a source file named kernel.cpp, I implement a few functions in the following manner:
#include "kernel.h"

void printf(uint8_t* str)
{

    static uint16_t* VideoMemory = (uint16_t*) 0xb8000; 
    static uint8_t x = 0, y = 0;
    for (int32_t i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i)
    {
        switch(str[i])
        {
            case '\n': // New line
                y++;
                x = 0;
                VideoMemory[80*y + x] = (VideoMemory[80*y + x]&0xFF00) | (int32_t)">";
                break;
            default:
                VideoMemory[80*y + x] = (VideoMemory[80*y + x]&0xFF00) | str[i];
                x++;
                break;
        }
        if (x >= 80)
        {
            y++; // Next line
            x = 0;
        }
        if (y >= 25)
        {
            for (y = 0; y < 25; y++)
                for (x = 0; x < 80; x++)
                    VideoMemory[80*y + x] = (VideoMemory[80*y + x]&0xFF00) | ' '; // Clear screen
            x = 0;
            y = 0;
        }
    }
}

extern "C" void fill_keyboard_buffer(uint8_t letter)
{
    static int32_t index = 0;
    command_buffer[index] = letter;
    printf(&letter);
    keyboard_buffer[index] = letter;
    if (index < 127)
    {
        index++;
    }
    if (letter == '\n')
    {
        index = 0;
    }
}

In addition to the kernel.cpp file, I have another file named kernel.h in which I declare these functions. The header file is as following:
#ifndef __KERNEL_H
#define __KERNEL_H
#include "types.h"
#define KEYBOARD_BUFFER_SIZE 128
extern "C" void fill_keyboard_buffer(uint8_t letter);
void printf(uint8_t* ptr);
#endif

For clarification, the types.h header file is declared in the following fashion:
#ifndef __TYPES_H
#define __TYPES_H
     typedef char int8_t;
     typedef unsigned char uint8_t; // signed byte, unsigned byte

     typedef short int16_t;
     typedef unsigned short uint16_t; // signed 2 bytes, unsigned 2 bytes

     typedef int int32_t;
     typedef unsigned int uint32_t; // signed 4 bytes, unsigned 4 bytes

     typedef long long int int64_t;
     typedef unsigned long long int uint64_t; // signed 8 bytes, unsigned 8 bytes

#endif

For some reason, when I compile the kernel file, I get the weird error:

error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘extern’

that happens in the line extern "C" void fill_keyboard_buffer(uint8_t letter); in the header file.
Any idea?
I tried a few solutions, like defining the function in the header file in the following fashion:
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void fill_keyboard_buffer(uint8_t letter);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

Also, this problem happens if I completely remove the function declaration as well, but this time with the printf function.

Can't reproduce what compiler and version do you use? What options? Does anything change if you don't use reserved names in your program (e.g., __KERNEL_H is reserved for compiler use, KERNEL_H is fine)?

@Yksisarvinen I'm using the gcc compiler and it's version is 11.4.0. I get the same error if I try using KERNEL_H instead of __KERNEL_H. when it comes to compilation flags there are some that I use but I don't think it affects this code since it has compiled a few times already and now "decided" to stop working for some reason.

So what has changed? Speculating, perhaps an accidental key press that got saved into the file? Perhaps in a potion of the file you didn't include in your post or correct, but didn't save?

You don't need the extern "C" on both the declaration and definition of fill_keyboard_buffer(), the one on the declaration will suffice. And why are you overloading the printf() function? Can't you use another name that is not already taken by the C standard library?

Can't reproduce.    I do get diagnostics on (1)  the statement VideoMemory[80*y + x] = (VideoMemory[80*y + x]&0xFF00) | (int32_t)">";   due to the funky type conversion ((int32_t)">")  (2)   undeclared arrays command_buffer and keyboard_buffer used in the definition of fill_keyboard_buffer().  I agree with my compiler on those diagnostics, and they aren't relevant to the problem asked about.   Removing the lines that cause those diagnostics, the code compiles clean.

@Peter sorry for not knowing, but what do you mean by can't reproduce? Do you mean you can't run this code on a similar enviroment?

I suspect the code shown differs from the OP's actual code somehow  (e.g. there is other code in one or more of the files - probably preceding the code shown - that has been omitted, but contributes to the errors).     If I had to guess, there is a missing ; or } or something similar in the omitted code.

@ThErOmAnEmPiRe   I copied the content of the files from your question manually into a source file and compiled (using a slightly old g++).   The only modification I made was replacing the line containing each #include directive with content of the named file  (which is exactly what a standard C++ preprocessor does).   No diagnostics other than the ones I mentioned (and they aren't even close to the diagnostic you specified).     Removing the lines for which my compiler produced diagnostics, the code compiled without error.

"Also, this problem happens if I completely remove [X]" -- The simpler your [mre] the better. We don't need to see your real code so much as something that reproduces the error. So remove what you can, and update your question with the minimal code. (That is, replace the current code with a minimal example; don't make your question longer by appending the new code to the end.) Along these lines, you probably could give your functions empty bodies, as in void printf(uint8_t* /*str*/) { /* Do stuff *? }.
